# Login between ASP.NET and PHP using web API

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, api, forms-authentication

Here's the problem:

The old website (PHP) is to be converted step by step into a new website (ASP.NET). PHP works with MySQL and ASP.NET with MSSQL.

A PHP script on server A should now log in to server B (ASP.NET) via web API call. The API call via Post arrives, but the API seems to ignore the Forms Authentication or does not set the cookie.

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, true);

My idea is to have the client log in to the new system via a PHP script using API. However, when I call the new page (ASP.NET), I am logged out despite having called it before (same browser).

Is there a way to log the user from server A to server B via web API, so that when browsing between the two systems, the user doesn't notice that he has been logged in to two different systems in the meantime? The whole thing should then also work in the other direction.

The forms authentication via the login form works without problems, but I don't want to login the user via Login.aspx, but via the API.

Ideas?